# Navigation html with Cheerio web page scraper

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, cheerio

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping) tutorial how to screen scrape with cheerio for Node.js and I'm 2-seconds away from just downloading the entire page and using Javascript to extract the information I need, which I'm sure is much more difficult than actually using Cheerio, but I'm having difficulty understanding now to navigate the HTML with Cheerio. 
 How do I extract the number '2' "blind-cow-white-number"?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="mainCows" class="row-fluid">
<div class="zone zone-content">
<article class="projection-page content-item">
<article class="post post-page content-item blind-cow">
<h1>blind cow</h1>
<div>
<div class="blind-cow-header" style="margin-bottom:15px">
<div class="blind-cow-list"> my list </div>
<div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 90%; text-wrap: none; text-align: center;">
<div class="blind-cow-white-number"> 1 </div>
<div class="blind-cow-white-number"> 2 </div>
</div>
<div class="blind-cow-died"> 3 </div>
<table class="blind-cow-table">
<table class="blind-cow-table">
<div class="blind-cow-Locations"> </div>
<br>
<div class="blind-cow-footer">
</div>
</article>
</article>
</div>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this with cheerios?
Is there a web screen scraper for node.js that allows me to use xpath instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheerio uses the same syntax and almost everything else as jQuery.

```
$(".blind-cow-white-number").eq(1).html();
```

Comment: The jQuery API is very well documented. http://api.jquery.com/ contains pretty much everything you'll need.